# Set value of select based on the route URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my backbone app I've got a select menu which filters some employees in a list using routes, it does this by department.

E.g. **localhost/#filter/HR** or
     **localhost/#filter/Accounting**

```
routes: {
    "filter/:type": "urlFilter"
},

urlFilter: function (type) {     
    this.directory.filterType = type;
    this.directory.trigger("change:filterType");
},
```

Then in my view:

```
filterByType: function () {
    if (this.filterType === "all") {
        this.collection.reset(contacts);
        app.navigate("filter/all");
    } else {
        this.collection.reset(contacts, { silent: true });

        var filterType = this.filterType,
            filtered = _.filter(this.collection.models, function (item) {
                return item.get("type").toLowerCase() === filterType;
            });

        this.collection.reset(filtered);

        app.navigate("filter/" + filterType);
    }
},
```

However if you visit one of those URL's direct the select menu is out of sync.

How can I keep the select in sync with the route, where the select option values equal All, HR and Accounting?

Answer (score 0):

Make onchange handler onto your list, and update URL correspondingly (by adding a parameter value of current list item). Prevent reloading the page when changing URL (google for it). Make sure the current list item is updated when you open URL with parameter (that is, at page load).